# Is it possible to lock an Access table?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, ado

As the title suggests, I have an Access 97 db and would like to know if it's possible to lock a table after insert then unlock it immediately?

I need to add a record and immediately get the AutoNumber of the added record (by ordering by desc). The problem is between I insert and retrieve there can be another add from something externally (which would get the wrong AutoNumber).

Unfortunately, I cannot use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` as it is not supported for an Access 97 database file (already tried and tested, ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868911/2144390)).

Comment: Refer [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-options-for-a-shared-access-database-mdb-HP005188297.aspx) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This is definitely a XY problem. Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve instead?

Comment: I need to add a record and as soon as a add the record get the autonumber of the added record (by ordering by desc) The problem is between I insert and retrieve there can be another add from something externally (which would get the wrong autonumber)

Comment: [This](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record) might help. Not sure it solves the problem you specified. It is unlikely to solve it. But you can at least avoid orderby query.

Comment: Thanks for the link @ Sriram Sakthive but I cannot use that as it is not supported in access 1997 (already tried and tested)

Comment: Look at this KB article: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/221931

Answer (score 2):

> I have an Access 97 db and would like to know if it's possible to lock a table after insert then unlock it immediately?

Not really. However, although you cannot use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` with your Access 97 database file you can still use a DAO.Recordset to add the record:

```csharp
// This code requires the following COM reference in your project:
//
//     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
//
// and the declaration
//
//     using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;
//
// at the top of the class file            

var dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\test\a97_files\a97table1 - Copy.mdb");
Recordset rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM table1", RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset);
rst.AddNew();
// new AutoNumber is created as soon as AddNew() is called
int newID = rst.Fields["ID"].Value;  
rst.Fields["textCol"].Value = "Record added via DAO Recordset.";
rst.Update();
Console.WriteLine("Row added with ID = {0}", newID);
rst.Close();
db.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help guys but i'm gonna select the same details I just inputted, this will return what is needed.

Comment: Think carefully before implementing this. You'll probably wind up doing a table scan after every insert. Even if all of your "details" fields are indexed you'll have to hit each of those indexes. In either case you'll increase contention on the database file and it is widely accepted that Access does not scale particularly well. In fact, you really shouldn't be using an Access database with ASP.NET *at all* (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database)).