# MS Access - C# - Retrieve the latest inserted guid

Tags: c#, ms-access

Is there a way to retrieve the latest inserted guid in access with C#?

I tried this: Created a table Cars with a field Id of type autonumber, replicationID and a field Name varchar(250).

```
var command = myConnection.CreateCommand();
command.Connection.Open();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Cars(Name) VALUES ('Pagani')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT @@Identity";
Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteScalar());
command.Connection.Close();
```

The issue which I am getting is:

```
Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

always shows `0`

**EDIT**

To create the table you can use this statement over the C# OleDb connection (I think that from MS Access query does not work)

```
CREATE TABLE [Cars] (
 [Id] guid not null DEFAULT GenGUID(),
 [Name] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Cars] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Cars_6515ede4] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
```

Comment: @Soner Gönül take care about editings...

Comment: your latest edit broke the question's formatting. It was OK before

Comment: I have made an edit and hope this is what is intended by OP! Do correct if I understood incorrectly!

Comment: In the edit it seems that I ran Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteScalar()); in a closed connection

Comment: @bubi but that's where the line is. The only thing that changes was the spacing. If you wanted that line as part of a phrase, you should *format it properly*

Comment: NOW it's perfect :). Thanks @Rahul Tripathi

Comment: What Access and driver version? `@@IDENTITY` works only with Jet 4.0 and above [according to the docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815629)

Comment: In fact, this may be a [duplicat of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868911/select-identity-in-access-always-returning-0) where the issue was found to actually be an old database

Comment: Actually I'm using Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0

Comment: Wait, Autonumbering works with *ints*, not GUIDs. It's not a type, it's a *property* of a numeric column. What is the field's type after all? Please post the table's definition

Comment: In MS Access 2007 you can configure it setting Counter on Data Type and ReplicaID on field dimension. The field type in DDL is guid but if I use DDL to create table I can't specify to automatically assign it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added the OleDb table create statement

Comment: I'm pretty sure returning a GUID is not supported in OleDb.  Heinzi's answer is a great alternative though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `SELECT @@IDENTITY` does not work for "ReplicationID" AutoNumber fields then the most likely way to retrieve such a value for a new record is to use an Access DAO Recordset insert, like this:

```cs
// required COM reference:
//     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(
        @"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Recordset rst = db.OpenRecordset(
        "SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [Cars] WHERE FALSE", 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset);

rst.AddNew();
// new records are immediately assigned an AutoNumber value ...
string newReplId = rst.Fields["Id"].Value;  // ... so retrieve it
// the returned string is of the form
//     {guid {1D741E80-6847-4CB2-9D96-35F460AEFB19}}
// so remove the leading and trailing decorators
newReplId = newReplId.Substring(7, newReplId.Length - 9);
// add other field values as needed
rst.Fields["Name"].Value = "Pagani";
// commit the new record
rst.Update();

db.Close();

Console.WriteLine("New record added with [Id] = {0}", newReplId);
```

which produces

```
New record added with [Id] = 1D741E80-6847-4CB2-9D96-35F460AEFB19
```

Comment: This is a good idea but it's hard to use because I need it in an Entity Framework provider.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is not exactly what you are asking for, but let me suggest an alternative solution which might solve your underlying problem.

Create the GUID in C# and pass it to your insert:

```
var newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

var command = myConnection.CreateCommand();
command.Connection.Open();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Cars(Id, Name) VALUES (?, 'Pagani')";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", newGuid);   // Note: OleDb ignores the parameter name.
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Console.WriteLine(newGuid);
```

GUIDs are unique. It really doesn't matter whether it is generated by your application or by the Access database driver.

This option is in all respects superior to reading the GUID afterwards:

- You only need one database access.
- It's less code.
- It's easier.

And you can still omit the GUID in your INSERT in cases where you *don't* need to know the GUID - no need to change existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if there is no way to retrieve the guid I will apply something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can try like this using the `OUTPUT` :</strike>

```
INSERT INTO myTable(myGUID)
OUTPUT INSERTED.myGUID
VALUES(GenGUID())
```

You can try like this:

```
string str1 = "INSERT INTO Cars(Name) VALUES ('Pagani')";
string str2 = "Select @@Identity";
int ID;
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
{
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str1, conn))
  {
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = str2;
    ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually the editor Soner Gönül inserted a mistake (just corrected) but select @@identity was runned in an opened connection. I try to use the same command to run select @@identity

Comment: @bubi what error? There was no change in the code, in fact it's the *latest* edit tha broke formatting. Or did you want to write a phrase including a code line but **forgot to properly escape it?**

Comment: @bubi: Did you try the code which I have added? Do let me know if you get issues in that? Also why in your question you stated as GUID?

Comment: @RahulTripathi Access doesn't have an OUTPUT clause [according to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834799.aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:- Yes, I will remove that as I dont think that is what OP was after. Got confused intially!

Comment: About latest code, the guid is not an int so it could not work (it works because it returns 0 that is wrong...). Also using the same command it continues to return 0.

Comment: What Access version? `SELECT @@IDENTITY` only works with Access 2000 and later. And autonumbering *doesn't work with guids*. What *is* the field after all, a GUID or int ? Are you confusing autonumbering with default values?

Comment: It's working ok with autonumber int fields. In this case I'm using a autonumber idreplica field (equivalent to sql guid fields)